# Dynamic return Type based on string

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to pass a string to a function and assign a dynamic type that is returned?

```
class MyService {
  aMethod(arg) {
    console.log(arg)
  }
}

Container.register('my_service', MyService);

// Internally Container holds a Object 
export interface IServiceInstance {
    name: string;
    type: Function;
    instance: Object;
}

const myServiceInstance = Container.get('my_service')

// myServiceInstance should be detected as type of MyService class
myServiceInstance.aMethod('Hello World') 

// Currently I use it like this. But if it is possible I want to get rid of that
const myServiceInstance = (Container.get('my_service') as MyService)
```

Comment: What is `Container`, does it support generic types? `Container.get<MyService>('my_service')`, for example. You will have to be specific about the type *somewhere*.

Comment: Isn´t `Container.get<MyService>('my_service')` exactly the same as `(Container.get('my_service') as MyService)`

Comment: It has the same effect. TS isn't magic; again, you will have to specify *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the type of container to add a method specializations by string constant:

```
// In a library for example
declare class ContainerClass {
    register<T>(name: string, ctor: new ()=> T): void;
    get (name: string) : any;
}
let Container: ContainerClass ;


// In your app
class MyService {
    aMethod(arg) {
      console.log(arg)
    }
  }

Container.register('my_service', MyService);
interface ContainerClass {
    get (name: 'my_service') : MyService;
}
Container.get('my_service').aMethod("");
```

This takes advantage of the fact that a type (interface or class) can be extended by declaring an interface in the same namespace and with the same name.

Comment: hmm.. looks like what I want is not really possible. My desire would be, that the get method returns the right type based on the input of the register function.

Comment: You need to add the extra declaration for this to happen, it will not happen automatically. But if you use this frequently, it is not that big a problem to add the method for each type you register