# TypeScript second parameter type based on first parameter type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, enums, overloading

I have an enum of possible values for the first parameter and I want the second parameter to be based on the first parameter. So, if NAME is given I want the second parameter to be as string. If AGE is given, I want the second parameter to be a number.

How can I do something like this?

```
enum KeyType {
   NAME,
   AGE
}

class MyClass {
   public static setProperty(key: KeyType.NAME, value: string): void { }
   public static setProperty(key: KeyType.AGE, value: number): void { } 
}
```

And I would want to call the method like this:
`MyClass.setProperty(KeyType.NAME, 'John');`

Also, this should show an error:
`MyClass.setProperty(KeyType.NAME, 5);` // 5 is not a string

In this example it doesn't work as the `key` type is wrongly defined (key type is actually the value of the enum, so key type is `0`).

I am also open to suggestions about a different approach to having this functionality of only allowing a specific type for a specific parameter key.

Comment: Do you mean you want it to work out the types from what you've happened to put into `MyClass`? What about things that could have more than one type? Is there a particular reason you're not just using properties `name: string;` and `age: number;`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want it to be an overloaded method. So, same method, but the type of the second parameter is based on the KeyType value of the first parameter. So, you suggest something like `MyClass.name = string`, but I want something like `MyClass.set('name', string)`. This way I can dynamically set a property value when the name is stored within a variable. Also, this way I have an `enum` of all available properties that can be changed.

Comment: You don't need the enum with `keyof`. And you can dynamically assign with `thing[name]`. But I think this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909089/dynamic-return-type-based-on-string

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will look into that, I didn't know about the `keyof` operator.

Comment: Hmm, this seems close to what I want: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#example-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use function overloads to get the type checking working properly:

```
enum KeyType {
   NAME,
   AGE
}

class MyClass {
   public static setProperty(key: KeyType.NAME, value: string): void;
   public static setProperty(key: KeyType.AGE, value: number): void;
   public static setProperty(key: KeyType, value: (string | number)): void {}
}
```

or simpler, just use strings:

```
class MyClass {
   public static setProperty(key: 'name', value: string): void;
   public static setProperty(key: 'age', value: number): void;
   public static setProperty(key: string, value: (string | number)): void {}
}

MyClass.setProperty('name', 42); // Argument of type '"name"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"age"'.
MyClass.setProperty('age', 42); // Ok
MyClass.setProperty('name', 'foo'); // Ok
MyClass.setProperty('age', 'foo'); // Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

And of course you don't have to list the literal strings in the overloads, you can group similar ones into a type definition:

```
type StringProperty = 'name' | 'address';
type NumberProperty = 'age' | 'salary';
class MyClass {
   public static setProperty(key: StringProperty, value: string): void;
   public static setProperty(key: NumberProperty, value: number): void;
   public static setProperty(key: string, value: (string | number)): void {}
}
```

Comment: Cool, does the first version actually work? So I just have to add another (ore general) function that contains all the other functions? I don't usually like using string as it's harder to enforce them and also harder to refactor.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I used the first version (with enums) combined with the latest tip of grouping properties of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using another approach, using an object.

For example: let's say that we are creating a function to send analytics data, so we have an event name and a payload about this event...

```
enum TEvents {
  productView = 'web/product/view',
  productPutInCart = 'web/product/put-in-cart'
}

type TLogEvent = ({ event, data }:
  {
    event: TEvents.productView,
    payload: {
      productId: number
    }
  } |
  {
    event: TEvents.productPutInCart,
    payload: {
      productId: number,
      amount: number
    }
  }
) => void

const logEvent: TLogEvent = ({ event, data }) => {
  ...
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but it's more of a work-around instead of an actual answer to the question. I think your method allows for more complex declarations but at the expense of having to write more code and also change the actual generated JavaScript and create more Objects for the sole purpose of compile-time type checking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
MyClass.setProperty(key: KeyType, value: string |number) {
  // check key type and throw error as appropriate 
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, the only issue that this will check the type at run time, not at compile time. So I won't get any TS error if I try to call the function with missmatched parameters.

Comment: It should show errors in your code editor. The key must be a KeyType enum and the value must be a string or number

Comment: Yes, but I want that if KeyType is `NAME` the value should only be a string, not a number. In your case the editor won't show error if I do `MyClass.setProperty(KeyType.NAME, 5);` but it should, as the name can only be a string.

Comment: @IsraelOnomeAgwa I believe the OP wants the type to be determined by the first thing assigned to that property, rather than the union of all types of things assigned to all properties.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The only alternative I can come up with is to have the function as    MyClass.setProperty(keyname|keytype, name?|string, age?|number)

Answer (score -1):

javascript only contain object, so if you want to use enum, just define it like and object then call it like:

```
var enum1 = { SMALL:"asjdh", MEDIUM:2};
console.log(enum1.SMALL)
console.log(enum1.MEDIUM)
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this approach - if your class has two properties like age and name, your setProperty function can get string or age and based on type assign to specific property, example:

```
class MyClass {
    public age:number;
    public name:string;

    setProperty(value: string|number) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            this.name = value;
        } else if (typeof value === 'number') {
            this.age = value;
        }
    }
}

let myClass = new MyClass();

myClass.setProperty("John");
console.log(myClass.name);
myClass.setProperty(60);
console.log(myClass.age);
```

Of course using this trick with value with two type (string or number) you can done it as you wanted:

```
setProperty(key: string, value: string|number) {
    if (key === 'AGE') {
        this.age = value;
    } else if (key === 'NAME') {
        this.name = value;
    }
}
```

But in this case you need to write more code to protect this part.