# Why TS can't recognize the type of a second parameter based on the first one

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I could see that TS can't recognize the type of a param if it's derived from another by using ternary and extends.

Simplifying what I'm trying to achieve:

```
enum Types {
  A = "a",
  B = "b",
}

type A = { a: string };

type B = {};

function fn<T extends Types.A | Types.B>(
  first: T,
  second: T extends Types.A ? A : B
) {
  if (first === Types.A) {
    second.a;
    // Property 'a' does not exist on type 'A | B'.
    //   Property 'a' does not exist on type 'B'.ts(2339)
  }
}
```

TS should have recognized that `second` has type `A` inside the `if` block. Since `first` is `Types.A`, `second` has type `A`, accordingly to the parameter type declared at the function signature.

I thought that the `extends` could be the problem here but I could check that TS can recognize the derived type correctly in the following case:

```
function fnWithMultipleTypes<T extends Types.A | Types.B>(arg: T) {}

function fn<T extends Types.A>(arg: T) {
    fnWithMultipleTypes(arg)
}
```

The `arg` from `fn` matches the type `T` from `fnWithMultipleTypes`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript second parameter type based on first parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092523/typescript-second-parameter-type-based-on-first-parameter-type)

Comment: Thank you for the bringing that one. I have seen before but it's about overloading. I'm more interested on achieving through another way, as is described in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `first === Types.A` narrows `first` not the type parameter `T`. In fact there is no way to narrow a type parameter.

What you could do is use a union of tuple types, and destructure the parameters in the parameter list. In newer versions of TypeScript the compiler will be able to follow that the destructured parameters are related:

```
enum Types {
  A = "a",
  B = "b",
}

type A = { a: string };

type B = {};

function fn(
    ...[first, second]: 
            | [first: Types.A, second: A]
            | [first: Types.B, second: B]
) {
  if (first === Types.A) {
    second.a;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2AZygbwLACgpQIJQC8UARAIYkA02uAQkaQEZXYC+22ALosPg2lDIAuKMk4AnAJYgA5lFYBuDlm5Io9YmkXKAZmBABjTpID2IKDpAAKGrigA6RwG0dk8WMqjgBswBMAuiK2diF2AD5QLm5iIvBIyPZ4nsjefiJ4-sGhIRFR7pyxPAm0yakgviK0mVgAlOi2kjpQVq75RITEcSiJdZg4dik+5fZkSv3sWKxAA)